# How can I bring out values from many rounds of diceroll?

Tags: python, spyder, dice

I have an exercise where I have to bring out the statistics of the rolled dice by one player from 30 rounds of rolling 2 dice each round. With this information I have to make a propability chart with a heatmap.    =   dice ℎ /    .
Anyone that can show an example on how I can set this up?

Comment: I'm not immediately sure how to make a heat map, but do you need help getting the data of the 30 random rolls too?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help. Store the 30 dice rolls of the 2 dices in a list and then in a pandas dataframe. By using Seaborn you can make a heatmap.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

dice1 = []
dice2 = []
for i in range(30): 
  dice1.append(np.random.randint(1,6))
  dice2.append(np.random.randint(1,6))

data = {'dice1': dice1, 'dice2':dice2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
sns.heatmap(data=df)
```

Comment: Why is it not useful?

Comment: You just finished the OP's homework. They asked how to go about it, not how to do it.

Comment: Ah ok, I am  quite new in this, but it make sence :) I just hoped I could help....